# React Native: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean.java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null reference object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have been using react-native-image-picker on my app for a while without problems but suddenly I'm getting the error on the title, afaik I haven't changed anything in my code so I'm not sure why it's giving me this error...

The modal for choosing gallery/camera doesn't even opens now!

https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker

```
"react-native": "0.64.0",
"react-native-image-picker": "^3.1.3",
```

```
const launchImgLibrary = async (index) =>
    {
        //Alert.alert('kaka');
        let options = 
        {
            storageOptions: 
            {
                skipBackup: true,
                path: 'images' 
            },
        };
        
        launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => 
        {
            //console.log('Response = ', response);
            if(response.didCancel) 
            {
                console.log('User cancelled image picker');
            }
            else if (response.error) 
            {
                console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
            }
            else 
            {
                let file = { uri:response.uri, name:response.fileName, type:response.type, title:'image' };
                
            }
        });
    };
```